# iOS - How to set screen brightness in Today Extension?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using this code.

`UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(1.0)`

This works well in app, But this not work in today extension.

How do I do this?

Comment: I don't think you can do this in a widget. What would happen if a couple of widgets requested different brightness at the same time? :)

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the comment!